# Get the size of HOG feature vector - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, svm, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst

I'm a beginner in image processing and I'm using MATLAB to extract HOG features from the images to train SVM classifier. The size of the training images is 480*640 pixels and I'm getting 167796 features with the default settings for the built-in MATLAB extractHOGFeatures function. However, when I test the model it gives me less features (216 features only!) knowing that the testing images have the same size of the training images. I get this error in MATLAB "The number of columns in TEST and training data must be equal".

Do you have any clue how to solve this problem and get feature vector with the same size for the training and testing sets?

Here is the code,

```
    [fpos,fneg] = featuress(pathPos, pathNeg);  
    %train SVM
    HOG_featV = loadingV(fpos,fneg);   % loading and labeling each training example


    %% Detection 
    tSize = [24 32];
    testImPath = '.\face_detection\dataset\bikes_and_persons2\';
    imlist = dir([testImPath '*.bmp']);
    for j = 1:length(imlist)
    disp ('inside for loop');
    img = imread([testImPath imlist(j).name]);
    axis equal; axis tight; axis off;
    imshow(img); hold on;
    detect(img,model,tSize);



    %% training
    function [fpos, fneg] = featuress(pathPos,pathNeg)
    % extract features for positive examples
    imlist = dir([pathPos '*.bmp']);
    for i = 1:length(imlist)
      im = imread([pathPos imlist(i).name]);
      fpos{i} = extractHOGFeatures(double(im));
    end
    % extract features for negative examples
    imlist = dir([pathNeg '*.bmp']);
    for i = 1:length(imlist)
      im = imread([pathNeg imlist(i).name]);
      fneg{i} = extractHOGFeatures(double(im));
    end
   end


     %% testing function
     function detect(im,model,wSize)
     topLeftRow = 1;
     topLeftCol = 1;
    [bottomRightCol bottomRightRow d] = size(im);

    fcount = 1;
    for y = topLeftCol:bottomRightCol-wSize(2)    
       for x = topLeftRow:bottomRightRow-wSize(1)
         p1 = [x,y];
         p2 = [x+(wSize(1)-1), y+(wSize(2)-1)];
         po = [p1; p2];
         img = imcut(po,im);      
    featureVector{fcount} = extractHOGFeatures(double(img));
    boxPoint{fcount} = [x,y];
    fcount = fcount+1;
    x = x+1;
        end
    end

  lebel = ones(length(featureVector),1);
  P = cell2mat(featureVector');
  % each row of P' correspond to a window

   [ predictions] = svmclassify(model, P); % classifying each window

   [a, indx]= max(predictions);
    bBox = cell2mat(boxPoint(indx));
    rectangle('Position',[bBox(1),bBox(2),24,32],'LineWidth',1, 'EdgeColor','r');
      end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you show your code, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

What's the size of `P`? Is it 167796 x 216?  If so then, you should not transpose `featureVector` when you call `cell2mat`. Or you should transpose `P` before you use it. You can also make `featureVector` a matrix rather than a cell array. Since you know that the length of the HOG vector is 167796 and you know how many images you have, you can pre-allocate it up front, and fill in the rows.

Comment: NO, I don't get this value for P!

Comment: Ok, what's the size of `img`, then?